# AS3 Background Patterns

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, background

Is it possible to create a background of patterns, all placed using code?

```
private function addCrystals(evt: Event) {
        if(cryCount <= 11)
        {
            genCry.x = GenCryX
            GenCryX = GenCryX + 109;
            genCry.y = -120;
            cryArray.push(genCry);
            cryCount = cryCount + 1;
        }
        if(cryCount >= 11 && cryCount <= 20)
        {
            genCry.x = GenCryX
            GenCryX = GenCryX + 109;
            genCry.y = -240;
            cryArray.push(genCry);
            cryCount = cryCount + 1;
        }
        addVect();
}
```

"genCry" is the movieclip that is used
GenCryX is the int value to add to the current movieclip's .x value (to place them side by side)
cryCount is the int value to tell how many movieclips are already placed.

What I tried to come up with was a wall of diamond patterns(each with the same width, height) place them such that the first row had 11 diamonds, the second with 10, the third with 11 to create a "solid" wall with each diamond of a different shade.

What I ended up with was a single diamond in the frame.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

You must create new instance of the 'tile' that you are adding on each iteration. I don't understand where you've created such. And yes, it is possible, you just need to twiggle around with the code.

Set tile's width and height, and always add the next tile to that position. It should be something similar to:

```
define width;
define height;
define currentPosition;

while (currentPosition is IN stage) {
    create tile
    tile.x = currentPosition.x;
    tile.y = currentPosition.y;

    currentPosition.x += width;
    if (currentPosition.x > stage width) { // reset position
        currentPosition.y += height;
        currentPosition.x = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm... but I need to duplicate the diamond to form a grid-like pattern, how would that work